# Versioning for two api wrappers in the same package?

Tags: api, namespaces, repository, wrapper, versioning

I have two api versions and two php api wrappers. Right now both wrappers are in two different repos. The reason for the two repositories is that the two apis are very very different. But I was thinking what would it look like if I combined them both in one repository and use different namespaces for each. It would look like this with a lot more.

```
Acme\Api\V1\Client
  Acme\Api\V1\Endpoints

Acme\Api\V2\Client
  Acme\Api\V2\Endpoints
```

My question is what would it look like maintaining both versions in the long run? I think here about fixing bugs for V1 vs fixing bugs for V2, doing major changes for V1 which would require major semantic version change for both. If I keep them separate I have better control over versioning of the package but I also lose some common functionality that they both share.

Answer (score 0):

Pull the common functionality out into a NuGet package that they both share. Then you can leave the repos separate and avoid duplicating work when updating common code.